# Fixed header - switch to static or absolute to scrolled off screen when content below hits

Tags: jquery, scroll, positioning

A very basic setup: *title-shim-container*. The *shim* ensures, that on page load, the *container* is kept at bottom of window to make room for a video live-stream in the background.

When the *container* is scrolled up and hits the *title*, the title shall be pushed off screen and drop down in its original position. The *container* is positioned relative by the jQuery Isotope plugin; that can't be changed.

The first part I got [in this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2zQZ/2/). But how to get the second part working? I got only this far :(

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", shimming);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", shimming);
    
function shimming() {
    var wheight = $(window).height();
    $('#shim').css('height', (wheight - 63));
} // this part up to here works

$(window).bind("load resize scroll", function () {
    var wheight = $(window).height();
    console.log(wheight);
    var wscrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(wscrolled);
```

I asked for this in previous posts without providing a fiddle, so I better delete those posts?

Thanks for advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a second to figure out what you were asking.  The comments in the fiddle were actually more useful than your question here, but I think this captures what you were going for:

```
if (wscrolled > wheight - 187) {
    $('#title').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#title').css('top', (wheight - 123));
} else if (wscrolled <= wheight - 187) {
    $('#title').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#title').css('top', 64);
}
```

The 187 comes from the combined height and margin of the tile along with the gap space left over by the shim.  The 123 is the height of the title and the gap space to keep everything lined up correctly.

-- Edited --

It occurs to me that it's worth adding an else if condition to prevent repeatedly setting the existing setting if there will be a lot of scrolling going on.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that does the trick! Finally, I got that reverse sticky header; I always thought that in that conditional statement, the height of the shim needs to be logged and changed as well. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J2zQZ/6/ for others to see.

Comment: Actually, why does the shim need no taking into the equation? Its height changes on window resize and therefore the position of the container in the document? Why do you think in your edit that that else if condition should be added?

Comment: @Systembolaget - As I re-read it, I'm not so sure the `else if` is necessary, or helps in the way I wanted it to.  I was attempting to prevent code execution if you get a whole bunch of scroll events with values like 230, 240, 260, etc.  They all fall into the block of code that's redundant execution.  I suppose you could circumvent that with a flag or something.  You could also put those values in css class and just have jQuery swap the class.

Comment: Ok, so far, I tried it in my sandbox - scrolling up/down in various browsers and on 2 tablet PCs and could not provoke any glitch, so to me what you suggested seems failproof.

Comment: @Systembolaget - I based all the calculations off of the window height.  Their are enough fixed values that you can go about it either way.  The important thing is that you come up with a top value that positions the bottom of the title with the bottom of the shim.